# Libgdx crashing when rendering polygonshapes

Tags: libgdx, polygon

I created some polygons in Tiled and load them in Libgdx and whenever this is done the game crashes. For rectangles i get no errors and everything runs fine.

Here is my code:

```
private static PolygonShape getPolygon(PolygonMapObject polygonObject) {
    PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
    float[] vertices = polygonObject.getPolygon().getTransformedVertices();

    float[] worldVertices = new float[vertices.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
        worldVertices[i] = vertices[i] / MainValues.PPM;
    }

    polygon.set(worldVertices);
    return polygon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same problem, i fixed it by not having less than 3 or more than 8 vertices inside a body.